# HikariCP and servicing threads

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework-2.0, hikaricp

This is more of a question about the working of the connection pool in the background.

Suppose I have a fixed size connection pool of 1. Using Java Play, I have a configured thread pool which has a fixed size pool of 10 threads. When external requests hit my app, let us assume that each of these threads has a multiple tasks in its queue (unbounded), and each of these tasks involves writing to the database (MySQL in this case).
With each of these threads now requesting db access from the single db connection, how does the connection serve them?

1. Does it complete one task per thread, and serve them all in a round robin fashion?
2. Does it serve all tasks in a thread's queue before moving on to the next one?
3. Does it serve N tasks per thread, and then move on to the next thread, where N is a configurable parameter? If so, where can N be configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above. The service order will be non-deterministic from the perspective of the pool.  The order will largely be determined by the structure and behavior of the Play thread pool.